# Как избежать при каждой итерации цикла два inner join-а в select-е для delete?

Tags: sql, oracle

Как избежать при каждой итерации цикла два inner join-а в select-е, которые я использую для delete, может есть возможность результат select-a сохранить в переменную и переиспользовать ?

Удалять необходимо, указывая batchSize, т.к., большой объем данных

```
begin
loop
    delete from BpmsByteArrayEntityImpl where id in
    (select BA.id from BpmsByteArrayEntityImpl BA
    inner join BpmsHistoricDetailEntityImpl HDE on BA.id = HDE.byteArrayRefId
    inner join BpmsHistoricProcessInstanceEntityImpl HPI on HDE.processInstanceId = HPI.id
    where HPI.endTime <= sysdate - 1
    fetch next ${batchSize} rows only);
    EXIT WHEN sql%ROWCOUNT = 0;
    commit;
end loop;
end;
```

Использую СУБД Oracle 12c

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что происходит в коде. `SELECT` возвращает одно и то же в каждой итерации цикла? Также не понятно, когда происходит `DELETE` - его вообще нет.

Comment: RomanMitasov, ошибся в запросе, поправил

Comment: Сколько остается записей в таблице после удаления? Больше чем удаляется или меньше? Один из способов это переименование таблицы, создание `CREATE AS SELECT`, обратное переименование.

Comment: По теме: "удалить из таблицы BpmsByteArrayEntityImpl указывая batchSize", вы задали уже 7 (семь!) вопросов, ни один из которых вы не отметили как решение. В связи с этим хотелось бы узнать, планируете ли вы дальше развивать эту тему задавая новые вопросы?

Comment: 0xdb, задача решена, был применен другой способ

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Надо так: `fetch ... limit` + *bulk binding* + `rowid`. Попробуйте, быстрее eщё не придумали:

```sql
create table t1 as 
    select rownum id, sysdate-level/24 created from dual
    connect by level <= 10e4;

declare
    batchSize constant number := 10000;
    type rowIDs is table of rowid;
    rids rowIDs;  
    cursor cur is 
        select rowid 
        from t1
        where created < sysdate-1;
begin 
    open cur; <<batches>> loop
        fetch cur bulk collect into rids limit batchSize;
        exit batches when rids.count = 0;
        forall ix in indices of rids
            delete from t1 where rowid = rids(ix);
        dbms_output.put_line (sql%rowcount||' rows deleted.');
    end loop; close cur;
end;
/
```

Результат (укорочен для наглядности):

```
10000 rows deleted.
10000 rows deleted.
...
10000 rows deleted.
9977 rows deleted.
```

---

**Важно**: здесь `delete` **только для примера**. Ни в коем случае не стоит с его помощью удалять большой объем данных.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по алгоритму, он должен итеративно удалять из таблицы по `batchSize` записей за одну итерацию.

Это означает, что при каждой итерации вложенный `SELECT` возвращает новые id записей, которые надо удалить.

Потому ответ - нет, нельзя. Вернее нельзя сохранить результат селекта, так как он каждый раз нужен новый.

По поводу оптимизации самого селекта - возможность этого зависит уже от данных которые там лежат, и решить эту головоломку предстоит вам самим.

Answer (score 0):

Для ускорения работы с SQL-запросами используются `BULK COLLECT` для выбора нескольких значений и цикл `FORALL` для выполнение SQL-инструкций единым целом.

Необходимо выбрать требуемые идентификаторы записей в коллекцию, а затем произвести изменения в цикле `FORALL`.

Простой пример

```
declare
  type t_arr is table of integer;

  v_arr t_arr;
begin
  select
    o.object_id bulk collect into v_arr
  from all_objects o
  where rownum < 100;

  dbms_output.put_line(v_arr.count);

  forall i in v_arr.first..v_arr.last 
    delete from z_temp d
    where d.id = v_arr(i);
end;
```

---

Не знаю насколько это поможет для удаления 10 млн.записей.

Comment: Alex R., а можно как-то сделать, чтобы он не по одной записи удалял, а список сразу, без forall? Может здесь как то условие поменять where d.id = v_arr(i);

Comment: Если без цикла, то коллекцию надо делать на уровне базы. Но, как я писал,  `FORALL` не удаляет по одной записи. Этот блок надо рассматривать как один оператор.

Comment: Но получается дольше почему-то, когда им удаляю 100000 записей для пробы